# EF: Querying a collection in an attached entity where the detached entity did not populate the collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Trying to find this answer online has been difficult, so I'm hoping I'm not asking a stupid question here.

I have two classes, `User` and `Login`.  A `User` can have zero or more `Login`s.  A `Login` has exactly one `User`.  (ASP.NET Identity)

Building out my `IUserLoginStore` implementation, I wrote these methods:

```
public Task<IList<UserLoginInfo>> GetLoginsAsync(User user)
{
    return Task.Run(() => GetLogins(user));
}

private IList<UserLoginInfo> GetLogins(User user)
{
    using (var context = _contextFactory.Get())
    {
        user = context.Users.Attach(user);
        var logins = new List<UserLoginInfo>();
        logins.AddRange(user.Logins.Select(x => new UserLoginInfo(x.LoginProvider, x.ProviderKey)));
        return logins;
    }
}
```

... now, in unit testing, I was mocking the `context.Users.Attach(User user)` method to return a `User` object with a populated `IList<Login>`, but... I'm not sure if EF would behave that way.

If I attach an entity to an EF database context as above, but the previously detached entity did not have the Logins property populated due to lazy loading, will I be able to access the Logins property after attaching it, or will it be null, throwing a `NullReferenceException` when executing this method?

I'm not ready to start integration testing yet, so I can't verify what the behavior will be.  I don't know if my unit tests are valid, as a result.  Can someone educate me on this?

Comment: Do you really need `Attach`? Why not just `Find(user.Id)`?

Comment: @IvanStoev I suppose I could, but wouldn't it generally be more efficient to `Attach` an entity instead of populating it from the database?

Comment: According to `DbSet<TEntity>.Find` help: *"Finds an entity with the given primary key values. If an entity with the given primary key values exists in the context, then it is returned immediately without making a request to the store. Otherwise, a request is made to the store for an entity with the given primary key values and this entity, if found, is attached to the context and returned. If no entity is found in the context or the store, then null is returned."* But yeah, in general you are right. So the answer to your question heavily relies on passed `user` being a proxy object or not